# Call requires API level 5 (current min is 3): android.app.Service#startForeground

Tags: android, sdk

I m trying to run an android source code in eclipse. The targetSdkVerison for this app is 5 . I m totally new to android and have installed the latest api's ( Android 4.1) . In some part of the code I m getting errors such as

```
    public void hideNotification(Service context)
    {
        context.setForeground(false);// error: The method setForeground(boolean) is undefined for the type Service
        getNotificationManager(context).cancel(NOTIF_PLAYING);
    }



    public void showNotification(Service context, long songId)
    {
        context.startForeground(NOTIF_PLAYING, newNotification(context, songId));//error :Call requires API level 5 (current min is 3): android.app.Service#startForeground
    }
```

I guess these are because incompatibility between different versions of sdk . How can I resolve the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `setForeground(...)` has been deprecated, and is no longer usable. See [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html) for more details.

You are getting this error because your minimum SDK level, defined in the manifest, is 3. [`startForeground(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) requires API 5+.

Now, in order to solve this, you cannot support anything below API 5; according to [Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), 99.3% of users have migrated to APIs 5+. To do this, set your `minSdkVersion` to `5`, and remove your call to `setForeground(...)`. (This will solve both error messages.)

*Note*: `setForeground(...)` has since **been removed from the SDK**, and should no longer be used, ever, at all.

Answer (score 0):

`Service.setForeground(boolean)` is a method that doesn't exist since API level 5.  It was replaced with [`startForeground(int, Notification)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

The documentation (from the link) suggests a method that you can use to support older devices while still targeting an API that is 5 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 2.0, this method is deprecated due to abusive use of applications in Android 1.5. Check out the following blog to see what has changed since then.

> http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html

Also visit this page to reference the new method (and a small sample).

> [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,
>   android.app.Notification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)